# Looking for a webserver as an alternative to my localhost?

Tags: json, webserver

I have an android app which successfully reads .json files from my localsever, however when the application runs on a mobile it is unable to read the files. I have had a nightmare trying to resolve the issue so I've given up.

I figured that perhaps uploading the .json files to an online web server would be an easier option. I have no previous experience with online web servers and wondered if someone could recommend a website?

I would only be using it to upload 5 .json files that are no more than 5KB and would probably only need it to be hosted online for about a month, I'm not sure if there is an alternative to a monthly subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of free web services. However, if you want to make it fast and easiest, try google sites. It gives you an evaluation time of about a month and it should be enough for you.

However, if you just want few files, you can go with any cheap web host such as bluehost and if you just want subscription on monthly basis.

You can also use amazon EC2 which provide you services on hourly basis so if you do not want to use it, just turn it off.

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/

Comment: excellent, thank you for the quick response and variety of options, I will accept this as an answer as soon as the timer enables me to.